# StackOverflowError while accessing parent method from inner class

Tags: java, stack-overflow, inner-classes

Please help me to find why getting StackOverflowError Exception while running below code.

```
public class HelloParent {

    HelloParent checking = new HelloParent();

    public class Hello{

        public void printFunction() {
            checking.printHW("hello ");
        }

    }

    private void printHW(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloParent helloParent = new HelloParent();
        Hello hello = helloParent.new Hello();
        hello.printFunction();

    }
}
```

Here I am trying to access parent class method from the inner class.

Comment: When you create a new `HelloParent`, it creates a `checking` instance variable of type `HelloParent`, which creates its own `checking` instance variable of type `HelloParent`, which creates its own `checking` instance variable of type `HelloParent`...

Comment: The best way to understand what's going on in situations like this is to use the debugger built into your IDE. Set a breakpoint on the first statement in `main`, and then step through the code statement by statement, stepping into methods and constructors. Using a debugger is **not** an advanced skill; it's something every beginner needs to learn very early on, so they can use it in situations like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HelloParent` has an instance field, `checking`, which is declared and initialized like this:

```
HelloParent checking = new HelloParent();
```

That code is inserted at the beginning of every `HelloParent` constructor*. That code *calls* the `HelloParent` constructor, and so gets run again, so calls the constructor again, and so gets run again, etc., etc.

You can't have an instance field that invokes the constructor of the class it's defined in.

---

* Technically, just after the (implicit, in this case) call to `super()`.

Answer (score 2):

> Here I am trying to access parent class method from the inner class.

In case of inner classes, the correct term is "enclosing class" not "parent class", since there is no inheritance relationship here.

You can access the method of the enclosing instance (the `HelloParent` instance associated with your `Hello` instance) by calling :

```
    public void printFunction() {
        printHW("hello ");
    }
```

or

```
    public void printFunction() {
        HelloParent.this.printHW("hello ");
    }
```

You don't need to create another instance of `HelloParent` within the `HelloParent` class (that's the cause of your `StackOverflowError`, as explained by others), so you can remove the `checking` variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is the cause of your infinite loop:

`HelloParent checking = new HelloParent();`

Remove it!

When you create a new `HelloParent` object in `main`, you in turn create a `HelloParent` object inside that object and so on recursively. This causes your stack to fill up and eventually overflow. This throws the `StackOverflowError`.

---

Hope this helps!